# Gather parameters with negative value

Tags: r

What is difference using negative symbol as part of `gather` , `-a.b` versus `a.b`

Executing code to convert 1 row per observations and 1 column per variable :

```
res1 <- data.frame("a.b" = c(1,2), c = c(3,4), "d" = c(5,6))

res1 %>% 
  gather(key = k, 
         value = v,
         -a.b)

res1 %>% 
  gather(key = k, 
         value = v, 
         a.b)
```

produces :

```
> res1 %>% 
+   gather(key = k, 
+          value = v,
+          -a.b)
  a.b k v
1   1 c 3
2   2 c 4
3   1 d 5
4   2 d 6

> 
> res1 %>% 
+   gather(key = k, 
+          value = v, 
+          a.b)
  c d   k v
1 3 5 a.b 1
2 4 6 a.b 2
```

res1 is :

```
> res1
  a.b c d
1   1 3 5
2   2 4 6
```

Comment: Negative implies we are selecting other columns instead of 'a.b'. Because there are two column 'c', 'd' n the first case and each have 2 elements.  with `a.b` there is only two values and that is the reason you have only 2 rows after `gather`

Comment: @akrun thanks but I feel im not understanding something fundamental when converting data frame to tibble. What impact does selecting other columns have on generation of the tibble?

Comment: It is the same behaviour as in the `melt`.  Nothing changed with `tibble` i.e `melt(res1, id.var = c('c', 'd'));melt(res1, measure = c('c', 'd'));melt(res1, id.var = 'a.b')`

Comment: @akrun res1 is already in tidy format as each observation has its own row and each variable its own column as can just use as_tibble(res1) ?

Comment: It would add the tbl_df classes as well.  But, is there any difference in behavior.  I couldn't find